# openvpn with multiple ips as user wise

Tags: openvpn

I need a vpn solution with openvpn server as below:

Suppose there are 5 employees in my team as named A,B,C,D,E etc.. And I've a openvpn server with 5 public IPs e.g. 103.255.98.1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. Now suppose I've make 5-users on server as A, B, C, D, E etc using useradd command and set password accordingly. Now my requirement is when emp A connect to server using A username and password then I'll provide him a static IP like 103.255.98.1 and when emp B connect to server using B username and password then he will receive different IP.

Is any possibility of such type of binding user-name with IPs on openvpn server ?

Comment: Is a solution using certificates, instead of username/password, acceptable as well? In case it is, read about the `client-config-dir` directive, it's explained in the man page.

Comment: Thank you for reverting. yes, certificate base solution is also acceptable. But I think this solution is work on private ips instead of public ips. I need allot public ips to different member.

Comment: I think this will work, if you run the OpenVPN server not on a private subnet, but instead on the public one.

Comment: I've make two file in ccd as below:
user1 =>    
ifconfig-push 10.8.1.1 10.8.1.2

user2 => 
ifconfig-push 10.8.2.1 10.8.2.2

And my iptable look like as below:
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 103.255.101.173/32 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.1.0/24 -d 103.255.101.175/32 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.2.0/24 -d 103.255.101.176/32 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0:0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/24 -o eth0:1 -j MASQUERADE

when i conect to user1 it able to get ip 10.8.1.1 but net not work

Comment: my server.conf file look like below:
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
client-config-dir ccd
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.2.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3

Comment: Put these information in your question and fix the formatting. Otherwise, it's not really readable...

Comment: I've added in previous question. if you need anything else then please update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it resolved using nating as below:

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 103.255.XX.XX
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 103.255.YY.YY

Now when user1 connect then he get ip:103.255.XX.XX
And when user2 connect then he get ip:103.255.YY.YY

Thank You